Firebase MessageBird extension cannot send sms
I'm not able to send SMS via MessageBird from Firestore. My request is failing with
WARN: firestore-messagebird-send-msg: send failed, got error: Error: api error(s): Request was not authenticated (code: 2

Per this comment, the issue seems to be that I'm using "test" access key instead of "live" access key. However, there's not way for me to set access key type.
On app.bird.com, I go to Security => Access Keys => Add new access key. I assigned Organization Owner role to the generated key and pasted in in Firebase in extension configuration. I'm getting the above error.
I'm able to send and receive the SMS directly from MessageBird dashboard.
